# existe la función $.create?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

Hola soy nuevo en esto de la programación quisiera saber para que sirve la funcion de $.create ya que la he encontrado en un script pero no se para que sirve este es un bloque donde la muestran

```
$.create("div", {
  className: "awesomplete",
  around: input
});
```

Entiendo que es para crear un elemento pero no se como funciona y que parametros lleva me gustaria que me dijeran si fueran tan amables.

Comment: Puede que sea un plugin de otra personas desarrollada en jQuery. http://api.jquery.com/ aquí tienes la API de jQuery, ya que no he visto ni me sonaba haber visto eso anteriormente

Answer (score 0):

Parece ser que es una función creada por el desarrollador, no es una función estándar de jQuery, el único ejemplo que se me ocurre es llamar la función dentro de un botón en un HTML:

```
<button id="create">Botón create</button>
```

Y que la función completa sea:

```
$("#create").click(function(event) {
    $.create("div", {
       className: "awesomplete",
       around: input
    });
});
```

Answer (score -2):

Eso que ves ahí no es una función, hace referencia a una Clase de Estilo llamada .CREATE

En jQuery haces referencia a las Clases de Estilo (CSS) con un punto (.) y al nombre del objeto (id) con un #

Saludos.

Eduardo.

Comment: los selectores en jQuery se escriben entre comillas `$("h1")`, `$(".clase")`,`$.("#id")`, etc. Los métodos llevan un punto delante: `.hide()`, `.click()`,...

Comment: Amigo entiendo lo que dices pero eso lo saque de un archivo que tiene extencion .js se como son las llamas a las clases pero no sabia que se hacia de esa manera yo sabia que sea hacia como lo tienes pero nunca de la manera que comento.